# Does git on cygwin support repositories on Windows network shares?

Tags: git, cygwin

I tried to set up a bare git repo for backup, as proposed in [nes1983](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52573/nes1983)'s reply to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887364/git-clone-to-external-drive-for-backup).

I am using git on cygwin. My local repository is on `/cygdrive/C/my-project`. When I set up my backup repository on the same disk, everything works fine.

However, if I set up the bare repo on a network drive `/cygdrive/H/backup-repo`, I get the following error:

```
bash-4.1$ git push backup
Counting objects: 101, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (85/85), done.
Writing objects: 100% (101/101), 62.60 KiB, done.
Total 101 (delta 17), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unpack should have generated 1f2087f7984f90b46a9cf90990d3399debedd3bc, but I can't find it!
To /cygdrive/H/backup-repo
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (bad pack)
error: failed to push some refs to '/cygdrive/H/backup-repo'
```

Are there any known limitations of git with Windows network drives, and are there any workarounds?

**EDIT:** I just found out: If I try calling the command `git push backup` again, it succeeds at the second or third try. However, calling the command again seems to be a bad solution, as I guess my repository might be corrupted when I get the message *failed to push some refs*. Any ideas what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had problems trying to push to repositories over the network using Cygwin.  Pulling has always worked, so I've tended to use that as a workaround.

If your workflow won't support that, you might find that setting up a git server allows you to get things working -- [Gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) works on Windows.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, pulling works for me as well. Still strange that push doesn't work.